# Make Ubuntu Server use less swap and more actual RAM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4, swap

I have a server with 128 GB of RAM and a 100 GB hard drive in it. It seems to use pretty much swap instead of using actual RAM when rsyncing disks. I found other questions on Stack Overflow with similar problems, but none had a real solution. This is the output of "glances":

[image: picture]

The server will normally never use 128 GB of RAM, so is it safe to disable swap? Would this increase the speed of the system or could it break something?

Or can I tell Ubuntu to use the physical RAM, instead of using swap?

Answer (score 5):

On your Ubuntu server you have a total of **1,38 GB of swap for 128 GB of RAM**.

On your screenshot **the system is using 970 MB of swap for 14,9 GB of RAM**, to my opinion is a standard amount of swap used by the system and far less to the 14,9 GB of RAM.

However it's a fair point to avoid your linux kernel to swap because is actually an "expensive" process in regard to its overall impact on the system performance.

Here **I would suggest to adjust the amount of swappiness on the system**, please find the following information for the [Ubuntu FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq/#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F) :

> What is swappiness and how do I change it?
>
> The swappiness parameter controls the tendency of the kernel to move
>   processes out of physical memory and onto the swap disk. Because disks
>   are much slower than RAM, this can lead to slower response times for
>   system and applications if processes are too aggressively moved out of
>   memory.
>
> 1. swappiness can have a value of between 0 and 100
> 2. swappiness=0 tells the kernel to avoid swapping processes out of
>      physical memory for as long as possible
> 3. swappiness=100 tells the kernel to aggressively swap processes out of
>      physical memory and move them to swap cache
>
> The default setting in Ubuntu is swappiness=60. Reducing the default
>   value of swappiness will probably improve overall performance for a
>   typical Ubuntu desktop installation. A value of swappiness=10 is
>   recommended, but feel free to experiment. Note: Ubuntu server
>   installations have different performance requirements to desktop
>   systems, and the default value of 60 is likely more suitable.
>
> **To check the swappiness value**
>
> `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
>
> **To change the swappiness value A temporary change (lost on reboot)**
>   with a swappiness value of 10 can be made with
>
> `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`
>
> **To make a change permanent**, edit the configuration file with your
>   favorite editor:
>
> `gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`
>
> Search for vm.swappiness and change its value as desired. If vm.swappiness does >not exist, add it to the end of the file like so:
>
> `vm.swappiness=10`
>
> Save the file and reboot.